# Unable to post comments to instagram using facebook graph api

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins, instagram-api

I keep getting the following error every time i try to post a comment to an instagram post using the facebook graph api.

```
"{"data":{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"GntDOEvIYS+"}}"
```

I have attempted to post a comment using the graph api explorer and it worked fine. It just doesn't work when I try to it from my app.

I have tried to post comments using my app with both a **facebook page token** as well as a **user access token** but both result in the same error message.

What could I be doing wrong?

PS: I am posting to the instagram business account connected to my facebook page.

Comment: Can you tell me that how you make calls like URL you create 
& any link for such page where apis are defined.
Its not related to your question but I am struggling in starting this thing

Comment: How did you fixed this issue, could you share details please... i can read media object, comments using same token. But when i try to reply on this comment i keep getting message - 'Application does not have permission for this action'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had added below permissions for your access token request to graph api:

**pages_show_list,instagram_basic,manage_pages,instagram_manage_comments**

It's working 100% using user access token